# What is going on with the types in this ghci session?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm learning Haskell, and I was playing around in ghci when I came across something very puzzling.

First, create a simple add function:

```
Prelude> let add x y = x + y
```

Note that it works with ints and floats:

```
Prelude> add 3 4
7
Prelude> add 2.5 1.3
3.8
```

Now create an apply function. It's identical to `$` (but not infix). It works like a no-op on add:

```
Prelude> let apply f x = f x
Prelude> apply add 3 4
7
Prelude> apply add 2.5 1.3
3.8
```

Ok, now make `add'` which is the same as `add'` but using `apply`:

```
Prelude> let add' = apply add
Prelude> add' 3 4
7
Prelude> add' 2.5 1.3

<interactive>:1:9:
    No instance for (Fractional Integer)
      arising from the literal `1.3' at <interactive>:1:9-11
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the second argument of `add'', namely `1.3'
    In the expression: add' 2.5 1.3
    In the definition of `it': it = add' 2.5 1.3
```

Wat.

Here are the types:

```
Prelude> :t add
add :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
Prelude> :t apply add
apply add :: (Num t) => t -> t -> t
Prelude> :t add'
add' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
Prelude>
```

Why does `add'` have a different type than `apply add`?

Is this a ghci oddity, or is this true in Haskell in general? (And how can I tell the difference?)

Comment: As soon as I hear "I was playing in ghci and I saw something strange," I think "Monomorphism restriction"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the [Monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-930004.5.5). When you define a value with a simple pattern binding (just the name, without any function arguments) and without a type signature, it gets a monomorphic type. Any type variables are tried to be disambiguated according to the [defaulting rules](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4), if that doesn't succeed you get a type error.

In this case, the `Num` constrained type variable gets defaulted to `Integer`.

You can turn off the monomorphism restriction with

```
ghci> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
```

or with the `-XnoMonomorphismRestriction` flag on the command line.