# Why does changing sq to point-free change the type

Tags: haskell, pointfree, monomorphism-restriction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is going on with the types in this ghci session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003535/what-is-going-on-with-the-types-in-this-ghci-session)

To try and practice a bit of haskell and learn about point free I was playing around with a function to square a number

so I started by defining

```
>let dup f x = f x x
```

so I could rewrite sq in terms of dup (without worrying about making dup point free for now)

```
>let sq x = dup (*) x
```

and checking the type of sq I see what I'm expecting to see

```
>:t sq
>sq :: Num t => t -> t
```

so I remove the x's and get

```
>let sq = dup (*)
>:t sq
sq :: Integer -> Integer
```

what am I missing?

Comment: Monomorphism restriction. Let me find a duplicate.

Comment: yep that's a dup - looks like I've got some more reading for tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have run into the monomorphism restriction.  Haskell will not infer polymorphic types for functions unless they are given in "function" style (not point free).  This would mean that `let sq = dup (*)` would not type check, but Haskell has so called "default rules" for standard numeric classes that mean it defaults to the monomorphic type `Integer->Integer"

```
Prelude> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
Prelude> let dup f x = f x x
Prelude> let sq = dup (*)
Prelude> :t sq
sq :: Num t => t -> t
```